# Script to open latest text file from a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, posix

I need a shell script to open latest text file from a given directory. it will be then copied to another directory. How can i achieve it?

I need a logic which will search and give the latest file from a directory (name of the text file can be anything (not fixed), so i need to find out latest text file)

Comment: `ls` provides a multitude of sorting options.  Maybe you should look there and see what you can come up with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can do something like this

```
#!/bin/sh

SOURCE_DIR=/home/juned/Downloads
DEST_DIR=/tmp/

LAST_MODIFIED_FILE=`ls -t ${SOURCE_DIR}| head -1`
echo $LAST_MODIFIED_FILE

#Open file
vim $SOURCE_DIR/$LAST_MODIFIED_FILE

#Copy file
cp $SOURCE_DIR/$LAST_MODIFIED_FILE $DEST_DIR
echo "File copied successfully"
```

You can specify any application name in which you want to open that file like gedit, kate etc. Here I've used `vim`.

xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application

Answer (score 5):

Not an expert in `bash` but you can try this logic:

First, grab the latest file using `ls -t` `-t` sorts by time `head -1` gets the first file

```
F=`ls -t * | head -1`
```

Then open the file using and editor:

```
xdg-open $F
gedit $F
...
```

As suggested by @ AJefferiss you can directly do :

```
xdg-open $(ls -t * | head -1)
gedit $(ls -t * | head -1)
```

Comment: While it's what you want to do, `F = ls -t * | head -1` will produce an error like: `bash: F: command not found`. You need assign the value to `F` using `F=$(ls -t * | head -1)`, or better yet just pass it directly to `xdg-open` using `xdg-open $(ls -t * | head -1)`

Comment: @AJefferiss: I fixed the syntax error (removed spaces around `=`).

Answer (score 2):

For editing the latest modified / created,

```
vim $(ls -t | head -1)
```

For editing the latest in alphanumerical order,

```
vim $(ls -1 | tail -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line (if are you sure that there are only files):

```
vim `ls -t .|head -1`
```

it will be opened in vim (or use other txt editor)

if there are directories you should write script with loop and test every file (if it's not a dir):

```
if [ -f $FILE ];
```

or you can also use find, or use pipe for get latest file:

```
ls -lt .|sed -n 2p|grep -v '^d'
```

Answer (score 1):

The **existing answers are helpful, but fall short when it comes to dealing with filenames with embedded spaces or other shell metacharacters**.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
# Get the most recently modified *.txt file.
# (On *assignment*, names with spaces, ... are not a concern.)
f=$(ls -t *.txt | head -n 1) 

# *Use* the variable enclosed in *double-quotes* to ensure that it is passed
# to the target command unmodified.
xdg-open "$f"      # could also use "$(ls -t *.txt | head -n 1)" directly
```

Additionally, some answer user all-uppercase shell variable names, which [should be avoided](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01) so as to avoid conflicts with *environment* variables.

---

<sup>[1] Due to use of `ls`, filenames with embedded *newlines* won't be handled correctly, but that's rarely a real-world concern.</sup>